Flutter 3.24.0 causing too much errors
I am using to run the E-Commerce shopping app template from here: https://github.com/abuanwar072/E-commerce-Complete-Flutter-UI
I used flutter 3.24.0 but got so much errors. Seems the errors were from the flutter package. How to solve this? I've tried flutter 3.22.3 also but to no solution. i also tried flutter upgrade, and checked flutter doctor but the doctor is not returning any error.


I just successfully cloned and ran that project.
I'm also on the latest version:
$flutter --version

Prints:
Flutter 3.24.0 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 80c2e84975 (3 weeks ago) • 2024-07-30 23:06:49 +0700
Engine • revision b8800d88be

Since the errors you are receiving are errors such that actual Flutter components aren't available, I'd suggest that you probably forgot to run the following:
flutter pub get

If that doest work, try running:
flutter clean also:
flutter clean
flutter pub get


Thank you so much @MendelG, the app is now working.

Follow These Step’s If Getting Error For Upgrade to Flutter SDK 3.24.0:
==> flutter pub cache clean
==> flutter channel stable
==> flutter pub get
==> flutter pub upgrade
==> (Optional) flutter pub upgrade win32
